# Vantiv Payment Method Not working in magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, worldpay

I am using vantiv payment gateway for my magento 2 site, it's working fine in magento front end with out any issue. and i also have success log message in log file, but it not working  in my magento admin back end. i have below error message in my log file.

```
2018-12-12T10:07:36+00:00 INFO (6): <litleOnlineResponse version="9.14" xmlns="http://www.litle.com/schema"
    response="1" message="Error validating xml data against the schema on line 27&#xa;Content of element &quot;expDate&quot; is incomplete"/>
```